# Usar Faker en Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema al usar `Faker` para migrar datos a mi tabla. Quiero importar 50 `fakes` nombres y countrys a mi tabla. Cuando ejecuto el comando `db:seed` no hace un `seed` de nada.

Propiedad model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Propiedad extends Model{

    protected $table = 'Propiedades';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'pais'];
}
```

PropiedadesTableSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use  Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PropiedadesTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        factory(App\Propiedad::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u){
            $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Propiedad::class)->make());
        });
    }
}
```

Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class PropiedadesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('propiedades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->integer('barrio');
            $table->integer('ciudad');
            $table->integer('pais');
            $table->boolean('cochera');
            $table->float('ambientes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('propiedades');
    }
}
```

databaseseeder

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
//        $this->call(DatabaseSeeder::class);
//        $this->call(PropiedadesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

factory

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define all of your model factories. Model factories give
| you a convenient way to create models for testing and seeding your
| database. Just tell the factory how a default model should look.
|
*/

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Propiedad::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'nombre' => $faker->name,
        'pais' => $faker->unique()->country,
    ];
});
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el contenido de DatabaseSeeder?

Comment: Ahi edito lo que postie

Comment: ¿En dónde defines tu factory? No lo veo por ningún lado.

Comment: ahi agregue el factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría debería funcionar solo con esta línea en el PropiedadesTableSeeder:

```
factory(App\Propiedad::class, 50)->create();
```

Al utilizarlo de la forma actual lo que estás haciendo es agregar una relación de Propiedad con Propiedad, la cual creo que no existe (y tampoco necesitas).

---

Además deberías quitar el comentario de DatabaseSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        // $this->call(DatabaseSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PropiedadesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahora me tira 
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `Propiedades` (`name`, `country`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Josephine Nikolaus, Ba  
  hamas, 2016-11-18 15:01:50, 2016-11-18 15:01:50))

Comment: En tu migración los campos se llaman `nombre` y `pais`.

Comment: Eso lo acabo de arreglar estaba mal puesto. 
Me quedaria arreglar esta linea.

factory(App\Propiedad::class, 50)->create();

Porque eso no anda

Comment: Debes tener algún error en el log, tal vez te falte hacer el llamado al namespace `App\Propiedad::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {`

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil (como creo que lo fue), puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Si pero no fue lo unico, tenia errores en mis columnas. Eso ya lo habia visto antes por eso lo comente

Comment: Bueno, por lo que comentas en tu respuesta veo que están ahí las observaciones que hice del include y la forma como se utilizó el factory. Marca tu respuesta entonces, ya que consideras que lo resolviste solo.

Comment: Tenes razon ! gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mi postSeeder

```
class PostsMediaSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('media')->truncate();

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        foreach (\App\Post::all() as $post) {
            if(rand(1, 10) > 4){
                $counter = 0;
                // max retries = 5 because sometimes faker return false
                while (!($fakeImage = $faker->image(null, 600, 400)) && ($counter < 5)) {
                    $counter++;
                }

                if ($fakeImage !== false) {
                    $post->addMedia($fakeImage)->preservingOriginal()->toCollectionOnDisk('featured', 'local-media');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mi databaseSeeder

```
 <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            if (app()->environment() == 'local') {
                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
                $this->call(PostsSeeder::class);
                DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
            }

        }
    }
```

Mi factory de esta forma trabajo yo mis seeder

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence(5),
        'description' => $faker->sentences(2, true),
        'content' => markdownContent($faker),
        'created_by' => App\User::admin()->first()->id,
        'status' => \Hootlex\Moderation\Status::APPROVED,
        'moderated_at' => time()
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenia un cambiado los nombres del schema y de mi faker. Por ejemplo en mi faker decia name y en la columna decia nombre. Tambien tenia un error de tipo de dato. 
Por ejemplo en la columna de tipo pais le habia asignado (integer), porque lo queria por id pero lo que me traia el faker era un string. 
Ahora esta andando todo

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('propiedades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('ciudad');
        $table->string('direccion');
        $table->string('pais');
        $table->integer('barrio');
        $table->boolean('cochera');
        $table->float('ambientes');
        $table->integer('superfice');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ModelFactory

```
$factory->define(App\Propiedad::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'nombre' => $faker->name,
        'pais' => $faker->country,
        'ciudad' => $faker->city,
        'direccion' => $faker->address,
    ];
});
```

Asi quedo en mi sql

[image: Base de datos]